# InfoWindows on google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Does i can do that kind of google infoWindows with the infoWindows function from google map api 3 when i click on the marker ?

http://i40.tinypic.com/25unplc.png

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content:"Hello World!"
  });

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
  });
```

I am not even able to do a line break in those information windows...

Comment: `content` can be any html string, including line breaks. is this not working for you? do you have more of your code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add html code to your infowindow to apply styles like:

```
var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
        '<h2>Meta Creation</h2><br/>'+
        '<div id="bodyContent">'+
        '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>';

infowindow.setContent(contentString);
```

**NOTE:** Just used some of the html tags to show example. Change according to your requirement.

Comment: Thanks, i didn't know i could use html tags